# I get UpdateException when i try to Update a collection property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am in an MVC4 application and i am using EF CodeFirst. 
When I try to run the following code:

```
 public void Autorizare(int cerereId, Persoana persoana)
        {

            var cerere = _db.Cereri.Find(cerereId);
            cerere.Autorizare.Add(persoana);            
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I get an error like this:

```
Entities in 'CerereDbContext.Persoane' participate in the 'Actiune_Executanti' relationship. 0 related 'Actiune_Executanti_Source' were found. 1 'Actiune_Executanti_Source' is expected.
```

i have tried Entity(Actiune).State = EntityState.Modified, but no results.

I have a main POCO:

```
  public class Cerere
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...            
        public virtual ICollection<Actiune> Actiuni { get; set; }
        ...

    }
```

the Actiune class looks like this

```
public class Actiune
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public String  Nume { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Persoana> Executanti { get; set; }
        public String Stadiu { get; set; }
        public String  Obs { get; set; }
    }
```

And Persoana:

```
public class Persoana
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public String Nume { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your model the Cerere does not have a property named Autorizare; however it does have one named Actiuni. Which is of type Actiune not Persoana which is what you are trying to add to it. Please post the rest of the Class Definition.

Comment: in my Cerere:  public virtual ICollection<Persoana> Autorizare { get; set; }

Comment: Have you tried setting the cerere entitystate to modified? EF needs to know that you have modified the cerere object or it will try and insert the persona object without also updating the cerere object.